# Modified Equation and Stability for Centred Finite Differences for Wave Equation

Tags: finite-difference, stability, wave-propagation

I am trying to use the modified equation to derive the stability condition for the finite difference approximation

$$
  \frac{u(x,t+\Delta t) - 2 u(x, t) + u(x, t -\Delta t)}{\Delta t^2} = c^2 \frac{u(x+h,t) - 2 u(x,t) + u(x-h,t)}{h^2}
$$

to the wave equation

$$
 u_{tt}(x,t) = c^2 u_{xx}(x,t).
$$

I know that the resulting stability limit should be

$$
\frac{c^2 \Delta t^2}{h^2} \leq 1
$$

but this is not what I am getting. Please tell me where I go wrong! Here is my line of argument:

**Truncation Error**. If we insert the continuous solution $u(x,t)$ into the left hand side of the finite difference stencil and use Taylor expansions
\begin{align*}
  u(x, t + \Delta t) &= u(x,t) + \Delta t u_t(x,t) + \frac{1}{2} \Delta t^2 u_{tt}(x,t) + \frac{1}{6} \Delta t^3 u_{ttt} + \frac{1}{24} \Delta t^4 u_{tttt} + \mathcal{O}(\Delta t^5) \\
u(x, t - \Delta t) &= u(x,t) - \Delta t u_t(x,t) + \frac{1}{2} \Delta t^2 u_{tt}(x,t) - \frac{1}{6} \Delta t^3 u_{ttt} + \frac{1}{24} \Delta t^4 u_{tttt} + \mathcal{O}(\Delta t^5) \\
\end{align*}
we can show that
$$
\frac{u(x,t+\Delta t) - 2 u(x, t) + u(x, t -\Delta t)}{\Delta t^2} = u_{tt}(x,t) + \frac{1}{12} \Delta t^2 u_{tttt} + \mathcal{O}(\Delta t^3)
$$

Making an almost identical argument for the right hand side, we find that
$$
c^2 \frac{u(x+h,t) - 2 u(x,t) + u(x-h,t)}{h^2} = c^2 u_{xx}(x,t) + \frac{1}{12} c^2 h^2 u_{xxxx}(x,t) + \mathcal{O}(h^3).
$$

Taken together, we find that

$$
u_{tt}(x,t) - c^2 u_{xx}(x,t) + \frac{1}{12} \left(  \Delta t^2 u_{tttt} - c^2 h^2 u_{xxxx}  \right)  = T(x,t) + \mathcal{O}(\Delta t^3) + \mathcal{O}(h^3).
$$

where $T(x,t)$ is the local truncation error. This is a standard argument to show that the finite difference stencil is second order accurate.

**Modified equation**. Following ideas introduced by Warming and Hyett, I now derive the modified equation. Since $u(x,t)$ is assumed to be the continuous solution, if it is smooth enough we have $u_{tttt} = c^2 u_{xxtt} = c^2 u_{ttxx} = c^4 u_{xxxx}$. Therefore, the expression above becomes

$$
u_{tt} - c^2 u_{xx} + \frac{c^2}{12} \left( c^2 \Delta t^2 - h^2 \right) u_{xxxx} = T(x,t) + \mathcal{O}(\Delta t^3) + \mathcal{O}(h^3).
$$

Thus the finite difference is a second order approximation to the wave equation, but a third order approximation to the modified equation

$$
u_{tt} - c^2 u_{xx} + a u_{xxxx} = 0
$$

with $a = \frac{c^2}{12} \left( c^2 \Delta t^2 - h^2 \right)$ and we can analyse the behaviour of this equation to understand how our finite difference behaves.

**Stability**. Finally, to assess stability, we insert a plane wave

$$
u(x,t) = e^{i (k x - \omega t)} = e^{i (k x - \mathbf{R}(\omega))} e^{\mathbf{I}(\omega) t}
$$

into the modified equation and figure out the dispersion relation. A frequency $\omega$ with a positive imaginary part means a solution that grows exponentially in time, indicating instability. Inserting the plane wave into the modified equation yields the dispersion relation

$$
\omega = \pm \sqrt{ c^2 k^2 + a k^4 } = \pm c k \sqrt{1 + \frac{a}{c^2} k^2}.
$$

Now for $a > 0$, the radicand is always positive and the root remains real. Therefore, $\omega$ does not have an imaginary part and the solution remains stable.

**But**: $a > 0$ corresponds to $c^2 \Delta t^2 - h^2 > 0$ or $\frac{c^2 \Delta t^2}{h^2} > 1$ which is clearly nonsense, given that the actual stability criterion is the other way round.

This looks like there should be a stupid, simple sign error somewhere but I can't seem to find it. Any help is much appreciated.

**Just to clarify, my question is where my argument goes wrong. I am aware that there are other ways to derive the stability condition.**

*Warming, R. F.; Hyett, B. J.*, [**The modified equation approach to the stability and accuracy analysis of finite-difference methods**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-9991(74)90011-4), J. Comput. Phys. 14, 159-179 (1974). [ZBL0291.65023](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0291.65023).,

Comment: What you wrote seems ok, though you should use the scheme to do the elimination of higher derivatives rather than the pde, as pointed out by Warming/Hyett. I have not seen anyone apply this to second order wave equation. There seems to be many issues with this approach, see e.g., https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-9991(90)90093-G and https://doi.org/10.1137/0907067, and its probably better not to use this approach to decide on scheme stability.

Comment: Interesting! Just reading through your references and the first on explicitly says that there are issues with multi-step methods like Leapfrog.

Answer (score 3):

I'm rewriting my answer. In fact, you don't need Taylor expansion to find out why $\frac{c \Delta t}{\Delta x} < 1$. I define second order numerical time and spatial differential operators as respectively:

$$D_{tt} u = \frac{u(x,t+\Delta t) + u(x,t-\Delta t) - 2 u(x,t)}{\Delta t^{2}}$$

$$D_{xx} u = \frac{u(x+\Delta x,t)+u(x-\Delta x,t)-2u(x,t)}{\Delta x^{2}}$$

The discrete form of your original wave equation is:

$$D_{tt} u = c^{2} D_{xx} u$$

And your solution is: $u(x,t) = \exp(ikx-i\omega t)$

So by putting that solution into that discretized wave equation and use discretized differential operators, we have:

$$D_{tt} u = -\frac{4}{\Delta t^{2}} \sin^{2}\Big(\frac{\omega \Delta t}{2}\Big) \exp(ikx-i\omega t)$$

$$D_{xx} u = -\frac{4}{\Delta x^{2}} \sin^{2}\Big(\frac{k\Delta x}{2}\Big) \exp(ikx-i\omega t)$$

So, finally:

$$\Big |\sin\Big(\frac{\omega \Delta t}{2}\Big)\Big| = \frac{c\Delta t}{\Delta x} \Big | \sin\Big(\frac{k\Delta x}{2}\Big) \Big |$$

You know that always: $\Big | \sin \Big ( \frac{\omega \Delta t}{2} \Big ) \Big | < 1$, so if $\frac{c \Delta t}{\Delta x} > 1$, for some values of $k$, which obviously your numerical discretization will be unstable, you would have $\frac{c\Delta t}{\Delta x} \Big | \sin \Big ( \frac{k \Delta x}{2} \Big ) \Big | > 1$ that is obviously wrong. So, you should always have $\frac{c \Delta t}{\Delta x} < 1$ to maintain stability of your discretized scheme.

It's good to see that for small $\Delta t$ and $\Delta x$, you have:

$$\lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} D_{tt} u = \lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} -\frac{4}{\Delta t^{2}} \sin^{2} \Big ( \frac{\omega \Delta t}{2} \Big )\exp(ikx-i\omega t) = -\omega^{2} \exp(ikx-i\omega t) = \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial t^{2}}$$

$$\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} D_{xx} u = \lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} -\frac{4}{\Delta x^{2}} \sin^{2} \Big ( \frac{k \Delta x}{2} \Big )\exp(ikx-i\omega t) = -k^{2} \exp(ikx-i\omega t) = \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}}$$

Furthermore, you can call $\sqrt{\frac{4}{\Delta t^{2}} \sin^{2} \Big ( \frac{\omega \Delta t}{2} \Big )}$ and $\sqrt{\frac{4}{\Delta x^{2}} \sin^{2} \Big ( \frac{k \Delta x}{2} \Big )}$ numerical frequency ($\tilde{\omega}$) and numerical wave number ($\tilde{k}$) respectively. So, the **numerical** dispersion relation is:

$$\tilde{\omega}^{2} = c^{2} \tilde{k}^{2}$$

Where you can easily deduce $\frac{c\Delta t}{\Delta x} < 1$, due to the fact that $\tilde{\omega} < \frac{2}{\Delta t}$ or $\tilde{k} < \frac{2}{\Delta x}$.

Comment: Wait, I agree up to u_xx = -k^2! But now the next derivative adds another +ik, hence u_xxx = -i k^3. Then another ik for u_xxxx = -i k^3 * ik = -i * i * k^4 = + k^4. Am I missing something?

Comment: Although this feels embarrassing, I put it into Wolfram Alpha - it confirms that (i*k)^4 = + k^4  ... hence the fourth derivative should come up with a positive sign in the dispersion relation?

Comment: @Daniel Sorry, answer is updated.

Comment: Thanks, Alone Programmer! I appreciate the answer. But I still can't see where my original argument goes wrong.

Comment: For multi-level methods as found for second order wave equation, the correct procedure to do Fourier stability analysis involves finding the roots of a characteristic equation and checking that all of them are less than unity in magnitude. See e.g., Section (1.9) of Gustaffson, Kreiss, Oliger: Time dependent problems and difference methods.

Comment: Hi cpraveen, thanks for the reference. I know the procedure but I was still surprised to see that the above argument goes wrong for a relatively standard discretisation. I'll check your references to see if they illustrate why my approach goes wrong.

Comment: @Daniel I'm not sure why you insist to find what's wrong with your approach, but in my opinion it's simply wrong and that's the reason why you can't derive the correct stability criteria here. Just look at your derivation. Let's say you simply put $u(x,t) = \exp(ikx-i\omega t)$ into the wave equation and derive the **physical** dispersion relation instead of **numerical** one that is provided in my answer. So, why you think that should give you the stability criteria? You added a higher order residual term as $a\frac{\partial^{4} u}{\partial x^{4}}$ by putting the Taylor expansion.

Comment: @Daniel But again you did not find the **numerical** dispersion relation and just find another **physical** dispersion relation, which obviously can't give you the stability criteria. Take home message is: you need to use **discretized** differential operators instead of exact ones to find the limit that those **discretized** operators would work asymptotically instead of exact differential operators and find the stability criteria that your **discretized** differential operators generate reasonable values.

Comment: The reason I want to understand what is wrong is that the approach works well and is widely used for problems with first order time derivatives. There must be some fundamental difference in the second order case and I want to understand what that is.

Comment: So, to rephrase, for, say, u_t + c u_x = 0 the analysis via modified equation works for a variety of FD schemes in precisely the way I used above. There, the modified equation represents the behaviour of the discrete solution. What changes here that this no longer holds?

Comment: Because: $u_{tt} = c^{2} u_{xx}$ $\rightarrow$ $u_{tt} + cu_{xt} = c^{2} u_{xx} + c u_{tx}$, where: $u_{tx} = u_{xt}$. So: $c \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (u_{t} + c u_{x}) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} (u_{t} + cu_{x})$, call $v = u_{t} + cu_{x}$, then: $v_{t} = cv_{x}$. Use central difference second order differential operator: $\frac{v(x,t+\Delta t)-v(x,t-\Delta t)}{2\Delta t} = c \frac{v(x+\Delta x,t)-v(x-\Delta x,t)}{2\Delta x}$, again: $v(x,t) = \exp(ikx-i\omega t)$. You find same **numerical** dispersion relation. **Difference is not in PDE itself it's based on your discretization**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101865/discussion-between-daniel-and-alone-programmer).